# mapping the keyword(UserRole) in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

In entity framework, database first approach, I have 3 tables [userrole], [role],[user]. In that when I am updating edmx file, then [userrole] is not coming in models classes.And [role] table is getting a relationship with [user] table (Which should not happen. It should have a relationship with [userRole]).

I guess it is somehow because of [userroles], that is already a keyword in db.

I add then all of of my tables individually one by one. First user, userRole, then [role]. I got [userrole] entity, but still relationship is not coming correctly. I am new to EF, Any help Please?

Comment: No, this is how EF maps junction tables (like `userrole`) in many-to-many associations. You can do everything you need to do with classes `Role` and `User` only.

Comment: Then how can I add [userRole] table ?

Comment: Do some reading on many-to-many associations and EF. Basically you just add roles to user.Roles.